# create an xml document in c# and store that file into bin folder of the project

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I want to create an xml file. I know how to create an xml file using linq to xml concept.
But i want to save that file in the bin folder of my project. How to do that.

```
 XDocument changesetDB = new XDocument(
                    new XElement("changes",
                            new XElement("change",
                                new XAttribute("path", changedFile),
                                new XAttribute("changesetID", changesetID),
                                new XAttribute("JIRAID", issueID))));
```

Now i want to save it in bin folder. Is it possible to do like that.
Thanks,

Comment: Yeah i too thought same.. but save means where it will save the file?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try out : [XmlDocument.Save Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22.aspx)

```
string path =  Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) ;
changesetDB .Save( Path.Combine( path , "data.xml"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
changesetDB.Save(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"myfile.xml"));
```

it will save `myfile.xml` in `bin/debug` folder

But if you want to save file to the `bin` folder, not the debug or release then you have to strip the Debug part of path from the path. You can do the following.

```
string binDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.TrimEnd(@"Debug\\".ToCharArray());
 changesetDB.Save(Path.Combine(binDir,"myfile.xml"));
```

This will save the file `myfile.xml` to the `bin` folder

Answer (score 0):

Your exe will be created in bin\Debug or bin\Rease so ..\ will be the bin folder. But have a look of your directories when you use your program out of vs.

```
changesetDB.Save("..\changesetDB.xml");
```